# groovy synchronizing singleton that holds sql instance

Tags: sql, groovy, synchronization, singleton

I've got this singleton

```
import java.sql.*
import groovy.sql.Sql
import groovy.transform.*
import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool

import groovy.util.logging.Log

@Singleton
@Log
class SqlPersistence {

    @Lazy def templates = new SqlTemplateEngine()
    @Lazy def sql = Sql.newInstance(
            "jdbc:h2:bookRental",
            "sa",
            "sa",
            "org.h2.Driver"
    )

    {
        sql.execute(
            ''' 
                create table $booksTable (
                    id int primary key,
                    title varchar(100)
                )
            '''
        )

        sql.execute(
            '''
                create table $usersTable (
                    id int primary key,
                    name varchar(50),
                    surname varchar(50),
                    age int
                )
            '''
        )

        sql.execute(
            '''
                create table $rentalTable (
                    id int primary key,
                    userId int primary key,
                    foreign key(id) references $booksTable,
                    foreign key(userId) references $usersTable
                )
            '''
        )
    }

    def findAll(table) {
        log.info 'attempt to select all from $table'
        sql.rows(templates.selectAll_template(table))
    }

}
```

As far as I understand I have to synchronize at least `instance` method, which is used to get the instance of the object

```
def sql = SqlPersistence.instance
```

What I'd like to know is what is the best way doing it? Override `getInstance` method? Or there is another way? Or maybe using something like `GPars`?

Comment: Use a connection pool, they've got this stuff covered

Comment: @tim_yates, you mean some external library (like `dbcp`) or there is some integrated in groovy?

Comment: Some external library ([Hikari](https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/)?)